# How to POST a JsonString and a HttpPostedFileBase picture to a Web Service?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

The Json string has this structure:
{"CODIGO_AGENCIA":"HN001001","CODIGO_USUARIO":"some user","CODIGO_CATEGORIA":1}

This is the parameter asked by the WS:

public async Task SubirImagenCategoria(string JsonString, HttpPostedFileBase Archivo)

//This is what I got so far, the web service returns error that the json string is empty, I am completely lost on how to proceed.

```
public static async Task<CustomJsonResult> SubirImagenCategoría(int CodigoCategoria, HttpPostedFileBase Archivo)
    {
        usuario = UtilClass.GetUsuarioSesion();
        var modelo = new SUBIR_IMAGEN_CAT();
        modelo.CODIGO_AGENCIA = usuario.CodigoAgencia;
        modelo.CODIGO_USUARIO = usuario.Nombre;
        modelo.CODIGO_CATEGORIA = 1;

        CustomJsonResult result = new CustomJsonResult();
        try
        {
            var JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelo);

            var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("form-data");

            StringContent jsonPart = new StringContent(JsonString.ToString());
            jsonPart.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
            jsonPart.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            formContent.Add(jsonPart);


            /* byte[] Bytes = new byte[Archivo.InputStream.Length + 1];
             Archivo.InputStream.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
             var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(Bytes);
             fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { FileName = Archivo.FileName };

             formContent.Add(fileContent);*/

            StreamContent filePart = new StreamContent(Archivo.InputStream);
            filePart.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
            filePart.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
            filePart.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Archivo.FileName;

            formContent.Add(filePart);

            var test = formContent;

            /*HttpContent jsonParam = new StringContent(JsonString);
            HttpContent fileStream = new StreamContent(Archivo.InputStream);
            formData.Add(jsonParam, "JsonString", "JsonString");
            formData.Add(fileStream, "Archivo", "Archivo");*/

            /*var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "JsonString", ("{\"CODIGO_AGENCIA\":"+usuario.CodigoAgencia+",\"CODIGO_USUARIO\":\""+usuario.Nombre+"\" ,\"CODIGO_CATEGORIA\":\""+CodigoCategoria+"\"}") },

            };

            HttpContent myBody = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);*/

            var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            String url = DataEntityLayer.Database.Environment.getFinalUrl(Util.UtilWS.subirImagenesCategorias);

        
            var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
            
            var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(url, formContent);
            string stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomJsonResult>(stringContent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Error = ex.Message;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[This is how I tested the WS from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFOMK.png)

Comment: what is the commented out code and `formData`, is that original test code that was working?

Comment: are you able to confirm a request is sent? (use capturing with tools like "fiddler", or step through debugging?), have you attempted to test the endpoint you're calling with tools like "postman" or curl? looking at this, I think issue here may be with "form-data", but I'm not certain.. I would expect it to be "multipart/form-data".  you should try adding/defining names with you add calls - `formContent.Add(jsonPart, "jsonPart")` as well.  `DefaultRequestHeaders` is also a considered here..

Comment: @BrettCaswell the commented code is one of the multiple tests I've been trying. Also, I do have the API that has the request, with a breakpoint I see that the JsonString parameter receives the image just as the image parameter.

I've used postman to test the endpoint and it works fine, no headers (well the default one's postman already has), just the two form-data parameters. This WS returns the URL where the image is saved and a reference number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts and almost having a mental & emotional breakdown, it finally worked.
Example 3 from this [link](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.Net.Http/MultipartFormDataContent/Add/php-multipartformdatacontent-add-method-examples.html) worked for me.

```
public static UsuarioSesion usuario = new UsuarioSesion();
    public static async Task<CustomJsonResult> SubirImagenCategoría(int CodigoCategoria, HttpPostedFileBase Archivo)
    {
        usuario = UtilClass.GetUsuarioSesion();
        var modelo = new SUBIR_IMAGEN_CAT();
        modelo.CODIGO_AGENCIA = usuario.CodigoAgencia;
        modelo.CODIGO_USUARIO = usuario.Nombre;
        modelo.CODIGO_CATEGORIA = CodigoCategoria;

        CustomJsonResult result = new CustomJsonResult();
        try
        {
            var JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelo);

            var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
           
            HttpContent JsonParam = new StringContent(JsonString);
            formContent.Add(JsonParam, "JsonString");

            var fileContent = new StreamContent(Archivo.InputStream);
            fileContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            fileContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"Archivo\"; filename=\"" + Archivo.FileName.ToString() + "\"");
            formContent.Add(fileContent, "file", Archivo.FileName.ToString());

         
            String url = DataEntityLayer.Database.Environment.getFinalUrl(Util.UtilWS.subirImagenesCategorias);
            var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(url, formContent);
            string stringContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomJsonResult>(stringContent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Error = ex.Message;
        }
        return result;
    }
```